# Correct way to getOrderByNumber() from my Plugin in Commerce 2

Tags: plugin-development, migration, plugin-craftcommerce2

I am migrating my plugin to Craft 3 / Commerce 2.

What is the best way to call another plugins method like `craft()->commerce_orders->getOrderByNumber($number)` from my plugins service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Craft’s core services are available via the `Craft::$app->getServiceName()->callServiceMethod()` signature.

For example, the Elements service would be `Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement()`

In the case of other plugins, most will make their Singleton “instance” available as a property on (or method of) their primary plugin class:

```
use craft/commerce/Plugin as Commerce;
// Maybe a class declaration, and inside your own method…
Commerce::getInstance()->getOrders()->getOrderByNumber('abc123...');
```

Comment: Ok, the 'as Commerce' did the trick, thank you!